# How can I include a subclass definition file into an Octave class

Tags: class, inheritance, octave

I have two octave classes defined in the same directory:

```
/home/me/octave/@myclass/myclass.m
/home/me/octave/@mysubclass/mysubclass.m
```

mysubclass is a subclass of myclass:

mysubclass.m:

```
classdef mysubclass < handle

    properties

        my_property = 0;

    endproperties

    methods

        function property = get()
        
            property = my_property;

        endfunction

    endmethods

endclassdef
```

myclass.m:

```
classdef myclass < handle

    properties

        subclass = mysubclass();

    endproperties

    methods

        function sub = get()

            sub = subclass;

        endfunction

    endmethods

endclassdef
```

However I don't seem to be able to 'include' the subclass definition in the same way as I might for e.g. C++. I tried adding

```
addpath("../@mysubclass/");
```

at various points in myclass.m, but I get a syntax error.

Can someone help?

Comment: (1) `classdef` files don't need to be in a `@` directory. (2) the *parent* directory of the `@` directory should be on your search path. (3) Don't modify the search path from your code. It is responsibility of the installation of your package (if you distribute it) to add the relevant directories to the search path.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo. Can classdef files all be in the same directory? Do they need to be in different files? I read conflicting answers.

Comment: Each is a different file, but they can all be in the same directory, next to function M-files.

Comment: You are mixing up several different concepts. Read the relevant section in the octave manual: https://docs.octave.org/latest/Object-Oriented-Programming.html Note the distinction between 'normal' classes, and 'classdef' classes. The former require a specific folder structure, whereas the latter don't. Furthermore, what you describe as 'class' and 'subclass' doesn't correspont to the code you gave. If 'subclass' is a subclass of 'class', then 'subclass' should inherit from 'myclass', i.e. subclass < myclass. Also read the difference between 'value' vs 'handle' classes.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Sorry, by subclass I did not mean 'a class that derives from another'; I only meant a class that is a member of another class, not one that inherits.